# Bash Scripting to pull data out of a csv

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a file with the following data:

```
20,2011/09/22,HUOT             ,CLAUDE       J,     ,DEX ,006403,MTRL,07:10,QBEC,10:29
020,2011/09/22,HUOT             ,CLAUDE       J,02001,DEX ,003470,MTRL,07:10,QBEC,10:29
020,2011/09/22,HUOT             ,CLAUDE       J,02003,DEX ,003307,MTRL,07:10,QBEC,10:29
020,2011/09/22,HUOT             ,CLAUDE       J,02004,DEX ,003309,MTRL,07:10,QBEC,10:29
020,2011/09/22,HUOT             ,CLAUDE       J,     ,DEX ,003310,MTRL,07:10,QBEC,10:29
```

I am trying to extract numbers in a specific field and in a specific range.

3400s, 4000s, and 7300s.  For the code above a would like to get 3470 as a result.

What is the best means of doing this in a bash script?

Comment: Are you free to use a scripting language like awk or do you want to just use bash built-ins

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is a good tool for this job.

```
awk -F, '$7 ~ /(34|40|73)[0-9][0-9]$/ {print}' filename
```

Comment: This works except it is printing the whole line.  Is there any way just to extract the print just the 3455

Comment: Sure, change `{print}` to `{print $7}`. If you want to remove the leading zeroes, then `{printf("%d\n", $7)}`

Comment: And mayby another small improvement: `/(34|40|73)[0-9][0-9]$/` should be `/00(34|40|73)[0-9][0-9]$/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
cut -d, -f9 data_file | while read number ; do if test $number -gt 3400 -a $number -lt 3500 ; then echo $number ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give you 3470 as result:

```
awk -F, '$7~/^00(34|40|70)/{print 1*$7}' inputFile
```

And for your given example, grep can do that as well:

```
grep -oP "(?<=00)(34|40|70)\d+" inputFile
```

the above grep cmd will give you 3470 too.

Answer (score 0):

Bash

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=","
while read -r line
do
    set -- $line
    [[ ${7:2} =~ ^(34|40|73) ]] && echo "${7:2}"
done < "file"
IFS="$OLDIFS"
```